# Annotate one dataframe with elements from another dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, annotations

I have been struggling with writing some code to annotate rows in one pandas dataframe with elements from another pandas dataframe based on some conditionals. The first dataframe is simply a table containing chromosome numbers and genomic positions:

```
    chr1    s1  
0   1   645710
1   1   668630
2   1   713044
3   1   738570
4   1   766600
```

The second dataframe contains some annotations based on the genomic region they span and on which chromosome they occur (s = start and e = end):

```
    chr s   e   state
0   chr1    10000   10600   repetive/CNV
1   chr1    10600   11137   heterochromatin
2   chr1    11137   11737   insulator
3   chr1    11737   11937   weak_transcribed
4   chr1    11937   12137   poised/weak_enhancer
```

Now I want to add another column to the first daraframe indicating which state belongs to that position. I have been trying iterating over the first dataframe and using conditionals like (because the position in df1 has te be between the two positions in df2):

```
"chr" + str(df1["chr1"] == df2["chr"] 
df1["s1"] <= df2["e"] and df1["s1"] >= df2["s"]
```

My general approach was to iterate over each row in d1 and then for each of those rows iterate over the entire df2, check the conditionals and if they are met, append the state in df2 to a new column in df1. So far no succes. As a novice python programmer: how would one approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframes are not too long, a solution could be to left join and then to filter out. First make sure that the modalities associated to chromosome match in the two dataframes (replace `1` by `chr1` in the first dataframe for instance) and then:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on="chr1", right_on="chr", how="left")
df = df[(df["s1"] <= df["e"]) & (df["s1"] >= df["s"])]
```

Comment: Unfortunately both dataframes do not have the same size and are rather long (df2 = ~700.000 rows)

Answer (score 0):

If your second dataframe with the genomic regions is already sorted, you can do a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) which will reduce the complexity from O(n) to O(log(n)). For large data sets and a lot of searches this can be quite a big improvement.

If it is not sorted and depending on how many of these look-ups you need to do, I would consider using a search tree which basically builds up a structure for performing binary search. However, you need to construct a (balanced) search tree before which might be too much of an overhead if you just need to do a small number of searches.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard, error-prone and slow to do using pure pandas. Use [pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges) instead, you can get the data back as a dataframe afterwards.

```
import pyranges as pr

c1 = """Chromosome Start End
chr1   10050 10051
chr1   713044 713045
chr1   11140  11141"""

c2 = """Chromosome Start End state
chr1    10000   10600   repetive/CNV
chr1    10600   11137   heterochromatin
chr1    11137   11737   insulator"""

gr1, gr2 = pr.from_string(c1), pr.from_string(c2)

j = gr1.join(gr2).drop(like="_b")
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# | Chromosome   |     Start |       End | state        |
# | (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) | (object)     |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------|
# | chr1         |     10050 |     10051 | repetive/CNV |
# | chr1         |     11140 |     11141 | insulator    |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# Unstranded PyRanges object has 2 rows and 4 columns from 1 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.

df = j.df
#   Chromosome  Start    End         state
# 0       chr1  10050  10051  repetive/CNV
# 1       chr1  11140  11141     insulator
```